# Doing j on multiple .SDcols groups in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to apply a function to different groups of data.table columns, and do this row-wise.
For example, in the following data.table, if V2 and V3 were one group, and V3 and V4 were the other one, I want to normalise row-wise group values, such that in every row, values in those columns that are the same group add up to 1.

```
library(data.table) 
set.seed(11)
DT <- data.table(V1=LETTERS[1:5],
             V2=sample(5),
             V3=sample(5),
             V4=sample(5),
             V5=sample(5))
```

I can do this for one group of columns, using SDcols, though I have to convert from integer to numeric first, because data.table doesn't do this automatically, performance reasons:

```
cols <- c("V2","V3")
DT[,paste0("V",2:5)] <- lapply(DT[,paste0("V",2:5)], as.numeric)
DT[, (cols):=(.SD)/sum(.SD), .SDcols=cols, by=1:nrow(DT)]
```

I also tried playing around with `for (j in cols) set`, but although this does the job, it looks very clumsy.

```
for (j in cols) {
 set(DT, j = j, value = DT[[j]] / DT[, base::sum(.SD), .SDcols=cols, by=1:nrow(DT)][,V1]) 
}
```

Also, I have too many groups of columns in my original data.table to do this repeatedly for each and every one. 
I've kind of hit the wall with this now, so any suggestion is very welcome.

Comment: Did you meant the second group as `V4 and V5` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are multiple groups, one option would be to `melt` the dataset into 'long' format as `melt` can take multiple `measure` patterns

Convert the dataset columns to `numeric` class

```
nm1 <- names(DT)[-1]
DT[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = nm1]
```

Then `melt` and `dcast` those columns

```
dM <- dcast(melt(DT, measure = patterns("V[2-3]", "V[4-5]"))[, 
        lapply(.SD, function(x) x/sum(x)) , V1, .SDcols = value1:value2], 
               V1~rowid(V1), value.var = c('value1', 'value2'))[, -1, with = FALSE]
```

and assign the output back to the columns

```
DT[, (nm1) := dM][]    
#   V1        V2        V3        V4        V5
#1:  A 0.2857143 0.7142857 0.2500000 0.7500000
#2:  B 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000
#3:  C 0.5555556 0.4444444 0.7500000 0.2500000
#4:  D 0.6666667 0.3333333 0.4444444 0.5555556
#5:  E 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5555556 0.4444444
```

Comment: Yes, that's it, the only problem for me is that I don't have a discernible pattern in column names, will have to work around that bit.

Comment: @novocaine You can pass the column names or index as a `list` i.e. `melt(DT, measure = list(names(DT)[2:3], names(DT)[4:5]))` or `melt(DT, measure = list(2:3,4:5))`

Comment: yes, I used the list, but the problem arises when not all groups have the same number of columns

Comment: @novocaine  In that case, there will be `NA` values filling up i.e `melt(DT, measure = list(2:3,4))`  There is `na.rm` argument in `sum` to remove i.e. `lapply(.SD, function(x) x/sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))`